# How to package projects and used NuGet packages + files?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, .net-standard

I'm working on a [.NET Standard 2.0 project called **ComputeSharp**](https://github.com/Sergio0694/ComputeSharp) and I'm having some trouble creating a NuGet package from it. Some info:

- The project only targets .NET Standard 2.0
- The project uses 2 referenced projects in the same solution, each using some other NuGet packages. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syBKF.png) is a screen of my current solution.
- <s>One of the project, `ComputeSharp.Shaders` also references two .dll files, `dxcompiler.dll` and `dxil.dll`. These two are referenced by that project with the following snipped in its .csproj file.</s> I made a PR to [`DotNetDxc`](https://github.com/tgjones/DotNetDxc) with the update .dll files, so I'll no longer need to manually bundle the two .dll files into my project. So this is no longer an issue ✅
- In the folder for the main `ComputeSharp` project, I also have a .nuspec file with the following structure, which also lists all the NuGet packages used by all 3 projects (note that the path for the `*.mustache` file goes up one directory because it's inside the `ComputeSharp.Shaders` project, and not the one from which I'm building the NuGet package, which is just `ComputeSharp`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>ComputeSharp</id>
    ...
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="SharpDX.Direct3D12" version="4.2.1-beta0-gab36f12303" />
      ...
    </dependencies>
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="..\ComputeSharp.Shaders\Renderer\Templates\*.mustache" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

- In order to create the NuGet package, I first build `ComputeSharp` in Release mode, then open a cmd in the folder for that project, and run:

```
nuget pack ComputeSharp.csproj -Prop Configuration=Release -IncludeReferencedProjects
```

- This does create a package that *kinda* looks ok. It contains the assemblies for all 3 projects, <s>the two .dll files I use</s> and the `.mustache` content file from the `ComputeSharp.Shaders` project.
- Once [uploaded to NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ComputeSharp/) I can see the list of all the dependencies for the package, as you can see [in this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndmuV.png). So, that <s>*looks*</s> is ok as well.

> **PROBLEM**: once I create a test project and install the NuGet package, <s>I notice two things: first get [this nice exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niK0N.png) when I try to use any APIs, which makes me thing the other NuGet packages haven't been installed correctly at all, and then I can't find any of the APIs from either of those packages (eg. I don't see the `SharpDX` namespace at all), which makes me thing the previous point is probably correct.</s> I have one last issue: the `.mustache` file (and relative parent folders) are not created in the build output directory, so I can't load it at runtime. I'm not sure why that is, since I did specify `copyToOutputDirectory="true"` in the .nuspec file.

I might be missing something obvious here, and I did check both the documentation and countless other SO questions on NuGet packages and whatnot, but I really couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I do have other NuGet packages uploaded, using the same method of including the referenced NuGet packages in the .nuspec file, and they work just fine when installed.

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT #1:** the indirect dependencies are now loaded correctly, so the last remaining issue is the content file not being copied to the build output directory (see changes above).

**EDIT #2:** closing this as it's too broad in scope, and the first part has been resolved already (.dll files and indirect package references). Opening a follow up question just for the issue about the content files not being copied [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57536112/how-to-setup-a-nuget-package-to-copy-content-files-to-output-build-directory).

Comment: `dxcompiler.dll` and `dxil.dll` are not your own outputs, I assume, and could be used by some other library used by the application that's using your package (enter DLL hell). In that case, they should be *implicit* dependencies, meaning that you don't declare them in your package and instead require the application to reference another package to get them. Granted, it's not ideal, but it avoids conflicts with other libraries. You could provide that package for now; your assembly would reference *the DLLs* but your package would not reference the package that provides those DLLs. ...

Comment: ..This allows the application (and your library) to switch to a canonical package in the future without battling other libraries over where to get those DLLs. You can declare a dependency on the canonical package when one becomes available. I'm not sure if that solves this exact problem, but it solves one I see over the horizon (thus not provided as an answer).

Comment: Hey, thank you for chiming in! That is correct, those two libraries are not produced by me. So, the thing is that those are not actually _referenced_ by the project (if I remove them, it still builds just fine), but instead they're loaded at runtime to P/Invoke into some APIs they expose (this is done through a 3rd party binding library). At least for now, I'd just like for this first alpha package to work at all. Do you have any clue on why I am getting those other issues, with NuGet dependencies seemingly not being loaded correctly? Thanks again!

Comment: Makes sense, and you do have it marked as an "alpha" package so that's good. Unfortunately, I have no clue at this point, and I dug into the dependencies a bit. It should be catching transitive dependencies. I'd suggest deleting all your `obj` and `bin` folders and letting it rebuild `project.assets.json` for all projects. That usually helps me when the "Dependencies" node has a yellow warning overlay icon even though everything's right.

Comment: I did try to clean everything but got the same result unfortunately. What I don't get is that if I rename the .nupkg file as .zip and open it, I can see the .nuspec there listing all the dependencies (as expected), so I really have no clue why VS isn't actually installing them in my test project, when installing my NuGet package :/ Thanks anyway!

Comment: Can the test project build successfully after you install the ComputeSharp package?

Comment: Hi @LanceLi-MSFT - yes, the test project builds just fine, as it's only using classes from the `ComputeSharp` project. It crashes as soon as `ComputeSharp` itself tried to use any of the referenced NuGet projects. Also, as a test, I tried merging the 3 projects into a single one (here: https://github.com/Sergio0694/ComputeSharp/tree/feature_repo-restructure), and building a NuGet package directly from VS, and this time all the NuGet dependencies were loaded correctly. I'm not sure why those don't work if I keep the 3 projects separate, since I'm using `-IncludeReferencedProjects`. Thanks!

Comment: I noticed that in your problem above, the test project can't even see the sharpdx namespace, but it works well in my machine. Have you cleaned the nuget cache and do a clean test?

Comment: Hi @LanceLi-MSFT - those are indeed working correctly now, I've rebuilt the .nuspec file from scratch and double checked all the dependencies, and it looks like they're now being installed correctly. The remaining issue now is the content file (and parent folders) not being copied to the build output directory. I've updated the question with info about this if you're interested. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for your details. Vote for your close :)